# Elasticsearch mapping does not include attributes from Rails key-value store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

Model:

```
class Item
    store :socket_store, accessors: [:sockets, :socket_count, :socket_link_count]
end
```

Mapping:

```
mapping do
  indexes :id,                    key: "value", index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :sockets,               type: "object"
  indexes :socket_count,          type: "integer"
  indexes :socket_link_count,     type: "integer"
end
```

But here's what my actual index looks like:

[image]

`socket_cout` and the othe 2 attributes are not at the root of the mapping, as if they were completely ignored.

I know I could create methods with a different name and add them to the to_indexed_json, but I would have guessed it should work as is.

Comment: Did you see there is an name inconsistency? Don't know if that is influencing something. `linked_socket_count` != `socket_link_count`

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I just recently renamed the field, but it was correct at the time. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

Since the accessors of the key-value store are not actual attributes on the `Item` model, they need to be added as methods in the `to_indexed_json` method:

```
def to_indexed_json
    to_json(include: [:stats], exclude: [:sockets_store], methods: [:socket_count, :socket_link_count, :sockets])
end
```

And that's it!